# Generate terrain with less chaotic noise

Tags: python, pygame, noise, terrain, heightmap

I made a heightmap generator which uses gradient/value noise to generate a terrain. The problem is, that the height map is too chaotic to look realistic.
Here's what I am talking about:

[image]

Here's the map without the colors:
[image]

I used a 257x257 grid of blocks with 17x17 gradients.
As it is visible, there are too many islands as well as there are some random small beach islands in the middle of the ocean.
Also, There are a lot of sharp edges, especially for the mountain terrain (dark gray).
What I would like is a smoother and less chaotic terrain, such as a large island, etcetera. How do I do that?

Comment: Ive seen people creating random lines and intersections meant to be lifting the height level afair. But I dont remember the full correct method.

Comment: Maybe have a look at this and its "see also" section https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise

Comment: Have you tried several iterations? First with high amplitude and large phase (not sure those are the right terms) for the rough terrain, mountains and ocean basins, then overlay that with a second, finer pass, adding smaller iregularities on top of that.

Comment: How does you code work, exactly?

Comment: I use a 17x17 grid of points which are assigned random heights. Then I use bilinear interpolation to calculate the remaining points. The entire image is a grid of 257x257 size.

Comment: Does the height of point (x,y) in any way correlate to the height of point (x+1,x+1) in the original 17x17 grid?

Comment: No, they are random. Since the nearest neighbouring gradient point is 32 pixels apart for all the gradient points, I figured it might not do much to relate them...

Comment: i used that before : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond-square_algorithm pretty realistic result

Answer (score 1):

In games, the most common noise generator for textures and heightmaps is the [Perlin Noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise).
I don't know from your answer is you actually want to create the noise generator or use it in your application.
If you are looking to create your own Perlin Noise Generator, [this would be a good starting point](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm).
I would however recommend using the noise (`https://pypi.python.org/pypi/noise/`) library available through pip using:

```
pip install noise
```

You can then use the `noise.snoise2(x,y,a,b,c)` function and fiddle with with the different parameters.

I would recommend reading this article: `http://simblob.blogspot.ch/2010/01/simple-map-generation.html` if you want to learn more about terrain generation.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this article](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/game-programming/polygon-map-generation/) where Amit walks through some map generation techniques. He even has sample code online.

In the article, he takes perlin noise as a randomization *parameter* to his terrain generator, but doesn't use it as the whole generator. The result looks really good. (I'd post a picture of the result, but I don't know of copyright issues just yet.)

While you're at it, Amit has written and curated on things game programming for years and years. [Here](http://www.redblobgames.com/articles/noise/introduction.html) and [here](http://www.redblobgames.com/articles/noise/2d/) are a few more articles of his on the subject. I hope this doesn't become a time sink for you, I've certainly spent many hours on his blog. :)

(PS. I prefer simplex noise over perlin noise. Same inventor, simpler implementation, and looks better to me.)

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, your sample may lack octaves and interpolation.

Depending on the implementation you are using, you may play with octave number, frequency, persistence / lacunarity, various interpolation techniques, etc...

Try playing / mixing with turbulence too (easy way to add fancy features to your height maps).
Many simplex noise (Ken Perlin's too, but scales better / faster on more dimensions) implementations deal with pretty complete set of parameters for you to play with, when generating your height maps.